# Creating a sequence in a list

Tags: erlang

I am very new to Erlang and I have a question about this function that returns a list counting down in ones. e.g. [3,2,1]

Why doesn't it work if you change the N-1 to N-2?

I'm looking to get the output to show [7,5,3,1]

```
-module(create_list).
-export([create_list/1]).

create_list(0) ->
       [];

create_list(N) ->
    [ N | create_list(N - 1) ].
```

Answer (score 4):

Because no matter how many times you subtract 2 from an odd number, you'll never get zero?

I've never even seen Erlang code before, but I suspect the fix is to add

```
create_list(1) ->
       [ 1 ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Safer to use positive check:

```
create_list(N) when N > 0 ->
   [N | create_list(N - 2)];
create_list(_) ->
   [].
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a function to do this:

```
lists:seq(From, To, Incr) -> Seq
1> lists:seq(7,1,-2).
[7,5,3,1]
```

Comment: It is very clear that this question is asked for learning purposes only of how Erlang and function (and integer math...) works, not to give the best solution to the problem